# How to interpret the random effect of a random slope model?

Tags: r, mixed-model, lme4-nlme, random-effects-model, glmm

I designed an experiment to observe the shading effect in the distribution of 2 species of crabs through time. So basically I have 4 levels of shading (no shade, 20%, 50%, and 80%) with 7 ID to each (28 in total), and counted the number of species A and B in different time points (0, 1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 10, and 13 months). Therefore I compared a random intercept model with a random slope model and the code and summary are as follows:

```
a <- cbind(ul=Eco$ul, uu=Eco$total - Eco$ul)
kable(a[1:224,])
modr1 <- glmer(a ~ time + shade + time:shade + (time|id), data=Eco, family = "binomial" (link="logit"), control = glmerControl(optimizer ="Nelder_Mead"))
modr2 <- glmer(a ~ time + shade + time:shade + (1|id), data=Eco, family = "binomial"(link="logit"), control = glmerControl(optimizer ="Nelder_Mead"))
anova(modr2, modr1, test="Chisq")

modr2: a ~ time + shade + time:shade + (1 | id)

modr1: a ~ time + shade + time:shade + (time | id)

npar    AIC    BIC  logLik deviance Chisq Df Pr(>Chisq)
    
modr2    9 1459.5 1489.9 -720.75   1441.5 
                       
modr1   11 1449.5 1486.7 -713.73   1427.5 14.04  2  0.0008938 ***

Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

    summary(modr1)

Generalized linear mixed model fit by maximum likelihood (Laplace Approximation) [glmerMod]

Family: binomial  ( logit )

Formula: a ~ time + shade + time:shade + (time | id)

Data: Eco

Control: glmerControl(optimizer = "Nelder_Mead")

AIC      BIC   logLik deviance df.resid 

1449.5   1486.6   -713.7   1427.5      206 

Scaled residuals: 

Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 

-4.7771 -1.1861  0.0898  0.9981  6.6329 

Random effects:

Groups Name        Variance Std.Dev. Corr

id     (Intercept) 0.464780 0.68175  
    
time        0.002967 0.05447  0.18

Number of obs: 217, groups:  id, 28

Fixed effects:

Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|) 
   
(Intercept)   2.403518   0.311480   7.716  1.2e-14 ***

time         -0.058801   0.032595  -1.804   0.0712 .  

shade20      -0.806281   0.420579  -1.917   0.0552 .  

shade50      -0.336302   0.425565  -0.790   0.4294    

shade80      -1.132901   0.417071  -2.716   0.0066 ** 

time:shade20  0.009717   0.041886   0.232   0.8165    

time:shade50 -0.028839   0.043842  -0.658   0.5107    

time:shade80 -0.096730   0.042004  -2.303   0.0213 *  

Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Correlation of Fixed Effects:

(Intr) time   shad20 shad50 shad80 tm:s20 tm:s50

time        -0.233  
                                        
shade20     -0.732  0.163  
                                 
shade50     -0.724  0.160  0.532  
                          
shade80     -0.744  0.172  0.546  0.539    
                 
time:shad20  0.170 -0.762 -0.160 -0.120 -0.126  
            
time:shad50  0.159 -0.719 -0.114 -0.183 -0.116  0.556  
     
time:shad80  0.179 -0.776 -0.126 -0.123 -0.155  0.592  0.554
```

My questions are: How to interpret the random effect?? How can I know the percentage of explanation from both random and fixed factors?? Do I need to know the variance of the residuals?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How to interpret the random effect??

Generally we don't usually interpret the random effects. We specify random effects to account for non-independence of observations with repeated measures. Random slopes are used to allow for the "effect" of a variable to differ between levels of a grouping variable (in this case `ID`).

According to the question you are interested in *the shading effect in the distribution of 2 species of crabs through time*. The estimates of the fixed effects in the model will answer this. There is no need to try to interpret the random effects in the way you are.

> How can I know the percentage of explanation from both random and fixed factors??

This kind of thing does not really make sense for a generalised linear mixed model. When you have random slopes for a variable, it is *both* fixed *and* random so to begin with, the idea of seperating variation in to fixed and random factors does not make sense.

> Do I need to know the variance of the residuals?

This is a logistic model, so there is no residual variation - or rather it is fixed, as the variance of the logistic distribution, $\frac{\pi^2}{3}$.

Comment: Could you explain that final remark? I do not see any use (or even validity) of the assertion "there is no residual variation."  Relevant threads include https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/185491, https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/128750, https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/253231, and https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/161581.

Comment: @whuber I mean that there will be no residual variation reported by `summary(model)` because logistic regression models do not have an error term.

Comment: They do have residuals, though.  For instance, `nlme:::plot.lme` graphically displays them, and ordinarily they do vary.

Comment: @whuber Agreed, there must be residuals (unless the model has perfect fit), it's just that there won't be any reported residual variation.